# Is there a way to perform two strike maneuvers in a round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

In a round an initiator can perform a single strike maneuver without a problem. I was wondering if there is a way to perform two strikes, each taking a standard action. Simple haste won't work, as it is already mentioned in Tome of Battle.

Materials from Dragon and Dungeon are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of a variety of ways to get a second standard action will work. Off the top of my head, an 8th-level factotum (*Dungeonscape*) can use cunning surge, or you can use up two (of three per day) charges on a *belt of battle* (*Magic Item Compendium*).